# Java FileReader gives a file not found error

Tags: java

This makes zero sense. I tried specifying relative and absolute path. I printed out current directory and then checked to make sure the file is there and I'm still getting this error. The file is not open in any other application. I tried making copies and moving them to other directories. Forward slashes, back slashes, double slashes, any kind of slashes I could come up with, but the error is still there.

Here's the complete code:

```
package module2;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.UnfoldingMap;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.data.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.marker.Marker;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.MapUtils;
import processing.core.PApplet;


public class LifeExpectancy extends PApplet {
    UnfoldingMap map;
    Map<String, Float> lifeExpByCountry;
    List<Feature> countries;
    List<Marker> countryMarkers;

    public void setup() {
        String curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println(curDir);
        lifeExpByCountry = loadLEMapFromCSV("LifeExpectancyWorldBank.csv");
        countries = GeoJSONReader.loadData(this, "countries.geo.json");
        countryMarkers = MapUtils.createSimpleMarkers(countries);
        map.addMarkers(countryMarkers);
        shadeCountries();
    }

    public void draw() {

    }

    private Map<String, Float> loadLEMapFromCSV(String fileName) {
        Map<String, Float> lifeExpMap = new HashMap<String, Float>();
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String[] line;
        while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            float value = Float.parseFloat(line[5]);
            lifeExpMap.put(line[4], value);
        }
        return lifeExpMap;
    }

    private void shadeCountries() {
        for (Marker m : countryMarkers) {
            String id = m.getId();

            if (lifeExpByCountry.containsKey(id)) {
                float lifeExp = lifeExpByCountry.get(id);
                int colorLevel = (int) map(lifeExp, 40, 90, 10, 255);
                m.setColor(color(255 - colorLevel, 100, colorLevel));
            }
            else {
                m.setColor(color(150, 150, 150));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the specific line that causes an error:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName));
```

I use Eclipse Mars IDE.

Edit: here's the bare minimum code:

```
package test;

import java.io.FileReader;

public class FileReaderTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:/Users/Denis/workspace/UCSDUnfoldingMaps/data/LifeExpectancyWorldBank.csv");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `System.out.println(fileName.getAbsolutePath());` and check if the path is correct

Comment: Can you boil this down to a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You have said that you are getting file not found error but it would be good if you could provide exception stack ..